# Is there a FutureBuilder alternative that would NOT require a Widget as the output?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

This is what I have for my background image:

```dart
 Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: FileImage(widget.lightAnimation.imageFile))),
```

```dart
widget.lightAnimation.imageFile: FutureBuilder(
             future: getImageFile(),
             builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.data,
           )
```

`Future<File> getImageFile()` returns a `File`;

The problem is that the output has to be a Widget and neither `File` nor `BoxDecoration` is considered to be a `Widget` The next closest one would be a `Container`, however that does NOT work in my case since the Container's child is very robust full of many variables, functions, etc.

In other words, what I could do instead is:

```
FutureBuilder(
             future: getImageFile(),
             builder: (context, snapshot) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: FileImage(snapshot.data))),
          ),
           )
```

However, in this case, I would have to move all my big child to the FutureBuilder since Container would take it with him, and I don't want to do it.

Is there any alternative I could use instead of FutureBuilder that would NOT require Widget as the output? Or maybe is there other possible way to make my background image with a future "builder/maker/function"?

Comment: Have you tried getImageFile().whenComplete(() => ...) Or .then()

Comment: I'm not sure where you'd add it. Can you please specify it?

Comment: i dont understand why `FutureBuilder` is not useful if you have some `Future`: you have some `Container` so why dont you want to return it from `builder: ....` code?

Comment: Because having FutureBuilder return a `File`, `FileImage`,`DecoratingImage` gives me an error that the FutureBuilder builder has to build/return a Widget, e.g. `Container`. So instead of returning/building this in the FutureBuilder:
             `builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.data,`
I would have to have return/build: `builder: (context, snapshot) => Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: FileImage(snapshot.data))),` which I don't want to do.

Comment: if you dont want `FutureBuilder` use `getImageFile().then((file) => setState(() => _file = file));` and add it in `initState()` method - but honestly this is a job for `FutureBuilder` to build your widget completely, with above code you are duplicating `FutureBu8ilder`'s code

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. Awesome!

Comment: well, i dont see anything awesome in this ;-) its a workaround and you should really use good, old `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what **`ValueListenableBuilder`** is for.

```dart
 ValueListenableBuilder<File>(
                valueListenable: imageFile,
                builder: (_, _imageFile, __) {
                  return  Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: _imageFile ));
                })
```

imageFile has to be `ValueNotifier<File>`. There are two ways:

- declare imageFile like so:

```dart
final imageFile = ValueNotifier<File>("initial_File");
```

- or in a separate class like this:

```dart
class ImageFile extends ValueNotifier<File> {
updateFile() => value='newFile';
}
```

It'd be better to implement FilePath as a listenable variable than the File, though.